# Debug HTTP request in node.js Express using PhpStorm

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, phpstorm, webstorm

I created a node.js Express app using PhpStorm v2021.1 (`File -> New Project -> Express`) and when I run it (`localhost:3000`) it runs successfully.

Then I want to debug my app API that respond to a HTTP post request. So I made HTTP request as below:
[image: http request]

Then I add new configuration as below:
[image: new config for http]

Finally I try click to debug:
[image: click debug Button]

But I can not see post request URL and data, so app runs like there is no any request:
[image: while debugging]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging express api works fine for me; not sure what you are debugging, and what's the reason for adding **Node.js** run configuration to **Before launch** of your HTTP request configuration: a process added to **Before launch** has to return an exit code, the main process is waiting for its exit code to start and thus doesn't start until the first process terminates. This is the way **Before launch** is designed - it's supposed to be used to run some sort of pre-processing before running the main process. But `bin/www` app doesn't exit, it starts the server, and it has to be running to make your API work.

Please remove your **Node.js** config from **Before launch**, start it separately in debugger (by choosing `bin/www` run configuration and hitting **Debug**) and then run your `GET`/`POST` requests to get the breakpoints in your application code hit

Comment: thanks,I did what you said and then read [this post on jetbrain](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000781750-How-to-debug-Node-js-code-) that helped me too. because I was setting **breakpoint** in wrong places